# Insert into multiple select results

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got this query :

```
INSERT INTO products_xsell (products_id, xsell_id) 
    SELECT px.products_id px_products_id, px.xsell_id, cross_added.products_id
    FROM products_xsell px, 
        (
            SELECT pc1.products_id, pm1.parent_id
            FROM products p1, products_cache pc1, products_modeles pm1
            WHERE p1.products_id = pc1.products_id AND pm1.products_id = p1.products_id
        ) AS cross_added
    WHERE cross_added.parent_id = px.products_id
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        px.products_id=px.products_id,
        px.xsell_id=px.xsell_id
    ;
```

My select is getting more than 1 record by comparing the field `products_id` of the table `products_xsell` with the field `parent_id` of the table `cross_added`. I want to be able to loop through the multiple results of that select and insert them one by one. But looking at how I do it I can't as we can only insert 1 value each of the select and not multiple results.

How can I insert with a select that's returning more than one result in my specific case ?

Table `products_xsell` has for example data as the following :

```
products_id   xsell_id
  1953          6235
  1953          1245
  1953          3265
  1423          1024
  1423          3623
  ...
```

My sub table `cross_added` gives me back, on the first loop where `cross_added.parent_id = px.products_id = 1953` :

```
products_id   parent_id
  1953          1953
  2563          1953
  6541          1953
```

This sub-table is the result of the first line :

```
products_id   xsell_id
  1953          6235
```

What I'm looking to do, is to loop through the sub table `cross_added` and for each product_id, I want to insert it into `products_xsell` with the same xsell_id to have this for the first line and the same for all others :

```
products_id   xsell_id
  1953          6235
  2563          6235
  6541          6235
```

Any idea how can I do that? :-)

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih I have added an example, is it clear now ?

Comment: I don't see why you could not insert more than 1 results coming from your select. However, you may have an error in your query: you specify 2 columns for your `INSERT` whereas the `SELECT` returns 3 columns.

Comment: @Lucas the select returns multiple rows, and the insert ... select needs to have only 1 result for each select. And no, I don't have any syntax errors. The insert will take from the select the column with the same name.

Comment: My bad for the syntax. I still don't understand why you state "select needs to have only 1 result for each select". For an INSERT ... SELECT, whatever results (rows) produced by the SELECT will get inserted as is.

Comment: @Lucas no, not whatever result, for EACH insert, you need to compare it to only ONE select result, if for EACH insert, you get multiple select results, it won't work. And you get an error that looks like this `Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`, which has a lot of meanings in different cases, in my case it means that the select returns multiple results for each insert.